# Code is not detecting the right amount in a file

Tags: file, python-3.x, io

Generally my code works fine except for one small part. In the file given below, the program should output the number of safe animals with red color or hard flesh. It should be 8 but I am getting 5. How would I fix this? The relevant excerpt is below. Thank you.

The text file:

```
#color     size     flesh     class
brown     large    hard      safe
green     large    hard      safe
red       large    soft      dangerous
green     large    soft      safe


red       small    hard      safe
red       small    hard      safe
brown     small    hard      safe
green     small    soft      dangerous
green     small    hard      dangerous
red       large    hard      safe
brown     large    soft      safe
green     small    soft      dangerous
red       small    soft      safe
red       large    hard      dangerous
red       small    hard      safe
green     small    hard      dangerous
```

And the code:

```
for line in infile:
    if line[0] != '#':
        data = line.strip().split()

        if data:
           animals = animals + 1

            if data[3] == 'dangerous':
                dangerous = dangerous + 1
            elif data[3] == 'safe' and data[1] == 'large':
                large_safe = large_safe + 1
            elif data[0] == 'brown' and data[3] == 'dangerous':
                brown_dangerous = brown_dangerous + 1                        
            elif (data[3] == 'safe') and (data[0] == 'red' or data[2] == 'hard'):
                safe_red_hard = safe_red_hard + 1



    print("Total animals: "+ animals + "\n")
    print("Dangerous: "+ dangerous + "\n")
    print("Brown and dangerous: "+ brown_dangerous + "\n")
    print("Large and safe: "+ large_safe + "\n")
    print("Safe and red color or hard flesh: "+ safe_red_hard + "\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principal problem was with the `elif` statements:

```
elif data[3] == 'safe' and data[1] == 'large':
    large_safe = large_safe + 1
elif data[0] == 'brown' and data[3] == 'dangerous':
    brown_dangerous = brown_dangerous + 1                        
elif (data[3] == 'safe') and (data[0] == 'red' or data[2] == 'hard'):
```

With this logic, any animal that is large and safe could never be counted also as safe and red or hard.  The solution is to use `if` statements instead:

```
animals = 0
large_safe = 0
dangerous = 0
brown_dangerous = 0
safe_red_hard = 0
with open('file') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if line[0] == '#':
            continue
        data = line.strip().split()
        if data:
            animals = animals + 1
            if data[3] == 'dangerous':
                dangerous = dangerous + 1
            if data[3] == 'safe' and data[1] == 'large':
                large_safe = large_safe + 1
            if data[0] == 'brown' and data[3] == 'dangerous':
                brown_dangerous = brown_dangerous + 1________________________
            if (data[3] == 'safe') and (data[0] == 'red' or data[2] == 'hard'):
                safe_red_hard = safe_red_hard + 1

print("Total animals: "+ str(animals) +"\n")
print("Dangerous: "+ str(dangerous) +"\n")
print("Brown and dangerous: "+ str(brown_dangerous) + "\n")
print("Large and safe: "+ str(large_safe) + "\n")
print("Safe and red color or hard flesh: "+ str(safe_red_hard) + "\n")
```